# getJSON returning 'undefined' after 4th element

Tags: javascript, json

I'm a beginner to js, and I'm trying to read a JSON document into an html table.
Well, the table creates, and it fills the table up correctly for almost all of it.
However, after the fourth data entry, the last column is all undefined.

*Information is faked*

[image]

Here's my code...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mapDiv.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
    <body>
<div id = "googleMap"></div>
        <script>
            function myMap() {
            var mapProp= {
              center:new google.maps.LatLng(36.3385,-88.8503),
              zoom:5,
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
            }
            </script>
            
            <script src="Redacted due to api key"></script>
            <hr>
            <div class = "container">
              <div class = "table-responsive">
                <table class = "table table-bordered table-striped" id = "customerData">
                  <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>CSZ</th>
                    <th>latLang</th>
                    <th>Image</th>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>

<script> 
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://cs1.utm.edu/~bbradley/map1/customers1.json", function(data){
      var custData = '';
      $.each(data, function(key, value){
        custData += '<tr>';
        custData += '<td>' +value.name+'</td>';
        custData += '<td>' +value.address+'</td>';
        custData += '<td>' +value.cityStateZip+'</td>';
        custData += '<td>' +value.latLang+'</td>';
        custData += '<td>' +value.image+'</td>';
        custData += '</tr>';
      });
      $('#customerData').append(custData);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Link to json

[json](http://cs1.utm.edu/%7Ebbradley/map1/customers1.json)

Comment: There is no image ```key```, ```value``` pair after 4th object in the array(its not json) you provided, and hence you are receiving ```undefined```..

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that.

Comment: Cool, Mistakes are unavoidable in programming world.. Happy coding..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the items in the JSON data don't have `image` properties. You should check for this and show something else in place.

```
        custData += '<td>' +(value.image || "No image available")+'</td>';
```

Comment: Ohhhh. I didn't even notice that.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Just for your clarification , i pasted here the item 3 and item 4 from json result:

```
  Item3:  {
            "name": "Trina Anderson",
            "address": "112 South Niles Avenue",
            "cityStateZip": "South Bend, Indiana 46617",
            "latLang": "41.6759656:-86.24418419999999",
            "image": "./people/NDExMTAuanBn.jpg"
        }
  Item4:      {
            "name": "Stephanie Mcghee",
            "address": "2435 Beaujolais",
            "cityStateZip": "O'Fallon, Missouri 63368",
            "latLang": "38.77378059999999:-90.70446230000002"
        },
```

in that case, item4 has no **image** attribute so in that case it is showing undefined when try to use **value.image**

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
        // here **value** is containing the each item from the json list at each iteration
      });
```

so you can either avoid to print the result or you can replace it by default image or anything else.

example:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
        custData += '<tr>';
        custData += '<td>' +value.name+'</td>';
        custData += '<td>' +value.address+'</td>';
        custData += '<td>' +value.cityStateZip+'</td>';
        custData += '<td>' +value.latLang+'</td>';
        custData += '<td>' +value.image || 'Image not exist'+'</td>';
        custData += '</tr>';
      });
```

Comment: I appreciate everyone pointing out that there was no image information after 4. I should've spotted it myself, but I've literally never seen a JSON file before this one.